# How to make Power Automate accept GET and POST requests?

Tags: http, power-automate

I have a Power Automate Flow that handles a verification and a payload from a webhook. I am using the HTTP Trigger of Power Automate. My problem is that I now need to handle both situations in one Flow. The verification requires the Trigger to be Method GET but the payload needs it to be POST. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

I have tried to use a second trigger but this is not possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not possible as far as I can work out.  You're going to have to adjust your thinking to cater for more than one flow unfortunately.

Comment: Is there any way to handle both with only one Trigger?